# Microsoft Lync Integration w/ IFTTT or Zapier?

Tags: if-this-then-that, zapier

I'm running Microsoft Lync for Mac (v14.2.1) on my work computer, where I do not have admin privileges.  [*NB: I think Lync is being renamed Skype for Business.*]

Lync should save conversation history, but it seems quite spotty and misses a lot.

Does anyone know a way to connect my Lync account to IFTTT, Zapier, or a similar service such that all conversations get saved somewhere *outside* the Microsoft ecosystem?